# MacBook Pro MiniDisplay to HDMI, Detects external display but the monitor is not getting input

Tags: macbook-pro, display, hdmi, displayport

I have a mid 2012 Macbook Pro running macOS Mojave 10.14.4.

When I plug in the external monitor it detects the display however on the external monitor screen it say no input.

I have checked all connections and tested them they are working fine.
MiniDisplay to HDMI cable tested and confirmed working on other another mac (mac mini mid 2013)

I checked the console when I plugged it in and am getting this error:

```
[ERROR] - Driver bug - rowBytes too small. Display 0x42732c0, ioModeID
0x8000100a, ioModeDepth 0x0, bytePerRow = 5120, width = 1680, bitsPerPixel = 32, 
minRowBytes = 6720 stored width = 1680. Forcing minRowBytes (possibly still wrong).
```

also

```
[ERROR] - Unable to find display pipe for IOFB service: 18203
```

Can anyone explain this error to me? Could it be a driver error?

The monitor I'm using is a Hitachi LE24K318A

This question is different from the others because the other questions don't show console outputs. I'm also not getting a "blank screen", I'm getting no input and errors.

Comment: The question and solution is the same - not having a “console output” doesn’t make it so significantly different that the problem and resolution aren’t identical.   In short, HDMI and mDP are *very* different signals including the lack of a clock signal in DP versus HDMI.

Comment: no its not its different obviously its a bug and I am asking if anyone has a work around or maybe can point me to the right direction your answer does nothing at all